# Link rendering in review pages? Possible bug?

Tags: discussion, support

Edit - Short Version:

I just noticed that I have miss-flagged an answer because I must have missread the answer text.

This is the original answer:

> Hi I had the very same issue after restoring. The below solution seems to help [I can't login to SharePoint 2010, what's wrong?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/i-cant-login-to-sharepoint-2010-whats-wrong)

Notice the link at the end, that point at another question about a similar (if not the same) issue. 
I am pretty sure that I must have flaged it because I didn't notice the link, so that answer would become:

> Hi I had the very same issue after restoring. The below solution seems to help. I can't login to SharePoint 2010, what's wrong?

Reading it that way it would give the impression of a comment "I have the same issue" posted like an answer.

Problem is: I have the felling that I didn't see the link because the text wasn't link coloured. This is an issue that I seems to have from time to time.

So here is the real question: did anyone notice any problem with the link coloring/rendering on the review page? If there is a bug I would like to hunt for it and post some info on stack meta, but I want at last to be sure that someone else is experiencing the same problem before risking to make the staff lose time hunting little pink flying elephants... I had some connectivitiy issue from time to time recently, so I suspect that this is just the browser going mad on me... but still I wanted to ask.